# Prime ng table on change detection(on push) calls the method inside the template

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

In an Html template I have prime Ng table and a button inside it.
Need to enable disable button based on some multiple conditions so have added one method in the template to make that decision like `[disable]="myMethod(data)"`,while clicking anywhere the method gets called every time.

Note: I have Also used lazy Loading in prime Ng table.

**Code tried** as below

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-client',
  templateUrl: './add-client.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-client.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

Any suggestions/ideas how to overcome this overhead.

Comment: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush will be invoked only if there is a change in your @Input data? did you have e@Inout property inside your app-add-client component?

Comment: Maybe this article helps you https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496